# HTML/CSS Layout Floating?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to layout something that initially needs to look like:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/xbCY636Pi1d9]

And then, I need to add 2 divs via jQuery to make it look like:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/xL485PQT]

I am trying to put everything into a `div` container, and then creating other divs for:

- the main square,
- the rectangle at the bottom,
- and then when required a div that contains 2 other divs (the 2 squares).

When the 2 squares are not there, the main square and the bottom rectangle must take the whole width of the container.

I've tried floating left the `div` containing the 2 squares and some other stuff but I fail.

**HTML** looks like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="videos">
        <video autoplay muted id="localVideo"></video>
        <br>
        <video autoplay id="remoteVideo"></video>
    </div>
    <div id="chatMessagesWindow"></div>
    <input autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Enter a message" id="chatInput">
</div>
```

**CSS** looks like:

```
#container {
  width: 850px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 580px;
}

#chatMessagesWindow {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 9px solid gray;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
}

#chatInput {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  float: right;
}


#videos {
  display: none;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

#videos video {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

In JavaScript I show `.show()` the `#videos` element.

## Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/67WLG/1/

Comment: Can you show us some HTML and perhaps some javascript? Also do you have to add the 2 boxes on the left or can they be hidden then displayed?

Comment: Just entered what I got.

Comment: Please use actual HTML not pseudocode, also alow me to introduce you to: http://jsfiddle.net/ if you want to set a demo of what you have done so far.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/67WLG/1/

Answer (score 1):

I have made this example in jsfiddle

try this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/67WLG/5/)

**JS:**

```
$('#container').on('click', function () {
    $('#videos').show();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#right_blk {  width:auto;display:table; }
#container {
  width: 850px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 580px;
}

#chatMessagesWindow {
  width: 98%;
  height: 562px;
  border: 9px solid gray;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  display:table;
}

#chatInput {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  float: right;
}


#videos {
  display: none;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

#videos video { width:99.1%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="videos">
        <video autoplay muted id="localVideo"></video>
        <br>
        <video autoplay id="remoteVideo"></video>
    </div>

    <div id="right_blk">
    <div id="chatMessagesWindow">
     asadad asdasdasd asds dsadasds asdasd asadad asdasdasd asds dsadasds asdasd asadad asdasdasd asds dsadasds asdasd asadad asdasdasd asds dsadasds asdasd asadad asdasdasd asds dsadasds asdasd asadad asdasdasd asds dsadasds asdasd asadad asdasdasd asds dsadasds asdasd asadad asdasdasd asds dsadasds asdasd asadad asdasdasd asds dsadasds asdasd 
        </div>
        <input autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Enter a message" id="chatInput">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this will help you!

html:

```
<div class="page-wrap">
    <div class="existed-content">
        <div class="main-content">this is a big div</div>
        <div class="main-footer">this is your footer content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.page-wrap {
    clear: both;
}
.existed-content {
}
.js-added-content {
    float: left;
    width: 130px; //this can be defined by yourself!
}
```

js(with jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    var STR = "<div class='js-added-content'><div>this is left top box!</div><div>this is left bottom box!</div></div>";
    var $pageW = $('.page-wrap');
    $pageW.prepend(STR);
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but didn't succeed. Could you take a look at the fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/67WLG/1/ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [CSS-Tables](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp): all of the handy layout features of HTML Tables with none of the content pollution! Or at least minimal content pollution. I did need to add a div to serve as a container for your chat messages and chat input elements:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="videos">
        <video autoplay muted id="localVideo"></video>
        <br>
        <video autoplay id="remoteVideo"></video>
    </div>
    <div id="chatContainer">
        <div id="chatMessagesWindow"></div>
        <input autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Enter a message" id="chatInput">
    </div>
</div>
```

Changes to your CSS basically involved adding in the new chatContainer id, getting rid of any floats, and adding in some `display:` lines. The [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) lines at the beginning are to make sure that any borders are taken into account when determining the width and height of elements. For some reason, the default is to ignore the borders and base sizes only on the interior of an element. You can get rid of those lines if you don't end up using any borders.

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    width: 850px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 580px;
    display: table;
}

#chatContainer {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table-cell;
}

#chatMessagesWindow {
    width: 100%;
    height: 530px;
    border: 9px solid gray;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#chatInput {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
#videos {
    border: 2px solid green;
    display: none;
}

#videos video {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The videos div can be hidden in JavaScript with this syntax: `<object>.style.display="none"` and shown with `<object>.style.display="table-cell"`, where  is of course the videos div.

The video elements themselves probably still need some positioning work though and some other elements may need sizing tweaks as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my own scenario, first, I would create a `global-wrapper` that will take the `850px width`.

It would contain the `#videos`( by default - `display:none;` ) and the chat `#container` which would be floated left and inheriting the width of `global-wrapper`.

On `#container`'s `click()`:

1. set the `#videos`'s width 1/3rd (for instance) and `float: left`.
2. set the `#container`'s width to remaining 2/3rd and `float it left`.
3. call the `show()` method on `#videos`

Instead of using jQuery's `css()` method, use predefined CSS classes and add them dynamically.